# Routing templates thats start with an underscore

Tags: templating, routes

More of a question than problem; I see this often - templates that start with an underscore. For example, `_entry.html`.

Reading the Craft docs:

> Note that if any of the URI segments begin with an underscore ('_'), Craft will return a 404, since template path segments that begin with an underscore are considered "hidden" from direct access

I guess I'm confused as to what I am hiding *from*. Is it so I can't directly browse right to the full path of that template?

`mysite.com/something/something/_template.html`

If you move the craft folder outside of the site root, I can't really get to that file can I? It just isn't obvious to me (yet) what the benefit is and when/where/why I need to start a template with and underscore.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, prefixing a template's filename with an underscore does what it says on the box – any underscored template will be excluded from route mapping.

A typical use case is to use underscores for partials or wrappers, e.g. "_mainmenu.html" or "_baseTemplate.html" – essentially any template that doesn't make any sense to load up or access directly in the browser via that template's path.

This isn't a mandatory thing, but a good practice.

Comment: It actually is required if you want to prevent URI to tempate routing for that URI (→ [routing case 6](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing)).

Comment: Good point, @carlcs.

Comment: It's an old topic, but I found it since I was looking for the meaning of prefixing underscores for folder names and I could only find this topic. 
So I might be asking a dumb question, if so, my sincere apologies :-), but I'm wondering: what does prefixing underscores for folder names do? Does that mean that all templates in that folder are being excluded from route mapping so you don't need a prefixed underscore for all templates inside that folder? 
I now do both: prefixing my folder and prefixing my template name, but I'm wondering if that's too much...

Comment: @Jan Right, if you prefix a folder name w/ an underscore, everything inside that folder (both templates and subfolders) will be excluded from routing. Hence, it’s not necessary to underscore a template sitting in an underscored folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I know for once and for all :-) !

Comment: Is there any way to override this behaviour on a local environment? (We have Commerce email templates in an _email folder and sometimes need to test them locally, which means renaming the folder, then renaming it back again)